# tsboot from the boot package in R doesn't run in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I need to generate a stationary bootstrap on a large sample. For this I use the boot::tsboot function from the boot package. When I run the function and look at my task manager, I see that only 15% of my CPU power is used by the function.
Even after explicitly defining the parallel = snow and ncpus = 7 options, the function still only uses 15% of my CPU power. Am I doing something wrong, or does the tsboot function not work in parallel?

I am working on Windows and have 8 cores.

Thanks in advance!

```
#generate some data
n <- 10000
k <- 10000
y <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = k)
for (i in 1:k) {
 y[, i] <- rnorm(n, i)
 print(i)
}

#bootstrap
result <- boot::tsboot(y, Rfast::colmeans, R = 500, l = 5, sim ="geom", orig.t = F, parallel = "snow", ncpus = 7)$t
```

Comment: Not sure you can use `snow` on Windows.